# Localize Android DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, datepicker

Is it possible to configure android.app.DatePickerDialog so that it is localized for the European format easily (exchange day and month and exchange the english button names with localized ones) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DatePickerDialog is localized by default. I tried it on a real device and the localization of the dialog adapts to the system default.

Comment: Additional information for application locale you can find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257014/set-language-to-french-in-android-datepickerdialog)

Answer (score 0):

You could design 2 `DatePickerDialog`s and use a condition based on the [`Locale` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) to choose between one or the other. However, as there is no "Europe" locale, but only countries locales, you might need to put the european locales in a list, and check if the locale is in the list. The current locale of the phone is accessed with : `Locale.getDefault()`

Comment: But the android.app.DatePickerDialog has no option to localize it to another format, or do i oversee it ? Do i have to rewrite it on my own ?

Comment: I don't know a lot about this kind of dialog, but I think you do have to rewrite your own.