# Numberpicker error while localization of app

Tags: android, localization, numberpicker

My app supports multiple languages. The number picker in all the languages is showing correctly.
[number picker in English and other languages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSTmX.png)

But when the app language is selected as Hindi, then number picker doesn't show the digits initially and shows in Hindi when the number picker is scrolled.

[Number picker in Hindi when the digits are scrolled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSbVQ.png)

I have tried to change the type face also and it is working in all the other languages except Hindi. Could anyone let me know how to prevent the number picker from changing the digits in Hindi language?

This is the class for my custom number picker.

```
public class MyNumberPicker extends NumberPicker{
    public MyNumberPicker(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void addView(View child){
        super.addView(child);
        updateView(child);

    }
    public void addView(View child,int index,ViewGroup.LayoutParams params){
        super.addView(child,index,params);
        updateView(child);
    }
    public void addView(View child,ViewGroup.LayoutParams params){
        super.addView(child,params);
        updateView(child);
    }

    private void updateView(View view) {
        if (view instanceof EditText){
            ((EditText)view).setTextSize(20);
            ((EditText)view).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Text));
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getResources().getAssets(), "Raleway-Medium.ttf");
            ((EditText)view).setTypeface(tf);

        }
    }

}
```

This is how I have used the number picker in activity.

```
MyNumberPicker  np_inhale =(MyNumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.np_inhale);
np_inhale.setMinValue(1);
        np_inhale.setMaxValue(50);
 np_inhale.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                i=newVal;
                h=np_hold.getValue();
                e=np_exhale.getValue();
                hafter= np_holdafter.getValue();
                r=np_rounds.getValue();
            }
        });
```

I have used this code for the localization.

```
String str_lang = "";
        if (lang_chng == 1) {
            str_lang = "hi";
        } else if(lang_chng == 2) {
            str_lang = "ru";
        } else if(lang_chng == 3) {
            str_lang = "fr";
        }
        else
            str_lang = "en";
        myLocale = new Locale(str_lang);
        Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
        android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
        config.locale = myLocale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Thanks.!

Comment: post your code here

Comment: I have updated my question with the code. Would be grateful if you could help me. @PriyankPatel

Comment: Post error which is shown in logcat.

Comment: is other string except number picker display in hindi when you change your language?

Comment: Yes all the other strings except number picker gets displayed in Hindi. @PriyankPatel

Comment: checkout this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257014/set-language-to-french-in-android-datepickerdialog/25486882#25486882 it looks like similar to your problem.

Comment: I had already checked that question before. My number picker contains digits upto 200 so it is not possible to add 200 digits in string. And I want the data in the form of integer for the calculations. @PriyankPatel