# Replacing a month name in a DatePicker?

Tags: android, datepicker

I need to replace the name of the AD months to Persian months name in a datepicker, how to do it?

```
public static final String[] MONTHS = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
```

to

```
public static final String[] JALALI_MONTHS = {"Farvardin", "Ordibehesht","Khordad","Tir","Mordad","Shahrivar","Meher","Aban","Azar","Dey","Bahman","Esfand"};
```

Comment: If my answer helped to you feel free to mark it as a correct and upvote it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to you use [`String resources`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#String) to do it

```
resources>
    <string-array name="months_array">
        <item>Farvardin</item>
        <item>Ordibehesht</item>
        <item>Khordad</item>
        <item>Tir</item>
        <item>Mordad</item>
        <item>Shahrivar</item>
        <item>Meher</item>
        <item>Aban</item>
        <item>Azar</item>
        <item>Dey</item>
        <item>Bahman</item>
        <item>Esfand</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

And then if you want it as a multilanguage create a new `strings.xml` named `values-fa` and then put inside this `strings.xml` it should be like this :

```
res/
    values/
        strings.xml
     values-fa/
        strings.xml
```

But if you want to change the `DatePicker` languague you should do something like this answer from [`@Igor K`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25486882/4385913), maybe it helps :)