# How to set default locale to English in DatePicker in android?

Tags: android, datepicker

when i am changing app language to Hindi ..Date Picker Language also Changing.
i tried [Set language to French in android DatePickerDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257014/set-language-to-french-in-android-datepickerdialog/25486882#25486882)
link but unable to solve?Can Anybody Suggest any Solution?

Comment: The DatePicker uses the default language settings of the phone. Why would you change it? If the phone is set to French, then the format will be the French format.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have same problem.

Comment: i have same issue ..i dnt want it

Answer (score 0):

You can reset Locale before the DatePicker is displayed.

Locale locale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
Locale.setDefault(locale);